# jQuery edit boxes and forms

Tags: jquery, input

I currently have a table that populates itself with domains and their relevant paths on a server, e.g.

`Domain       Path     Functions


example.com  /home/domain       delete`

The domains are grabbed from a PHP array, but thats the general idea.
Now, I want to be able to put an edit button next to my delete button, and when clicked the two fields turn into edit boxes (so the data can be edited and then updated via ajax to the server).
I've been using jeditable for this, but it doesn't really suffice.

Also, I'm wanting an add button, which when clicked creates a new row which data can then be put into and sent to the server.

I've looked around and tried reading the similar questions here, but I'm not sure what the best method to use is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Lee.

Comment: What isn't jeditable doing that you want it to do? It seems like you could just enable/disable it on edit button click?

Answer (score 0):

@Brandi -

I need to be able to have both boxes editable at once, not one at a time.